# Spring Kafka DLT publishing is not working

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-dlt

I'm using spring boot v. 2.7.9 and spring-kafka v. 2.8.8.
I setup a simple Consumer in order to test DLT publishing on error.
I'm not using any `@Configuration` class but only `spring.kafka...` properties in `application.properties`.

This is my Consumer

```
@Component
public class MyConsumer {
  @KafkaListener(topics="my-topic")
  public void receive(
    ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    System.out.println(record);
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler() {
    return new DefaultErrorHandler((rec, ex) -> {
      System.out.println("publishing into DLT");
    }, new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L));
  }
}
```

When I produce a message into `my-topic` topic I see in loop the record printed by `receive()` method followed by `publishing into DLT`. No record is published inside `my-topic.DLT` topic.

What's wrong?

Comment: Please show your Spring config? Your handler here is just printing, not using a KafkaTemplate for sending the record anywhere. More specifically, what are your producer properties?

Comment: Solved the problem of the loop, I was using a wrong key-serializer. But no record is sent to DLT topic.  From https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#default-eh I see no explicit KafkaTemplate for sending

Comment: `e.g. send to a dead-letter topic`..... This means that **you** need to do that, as an example of "handling an error" , not that it's done for you

Comment: Add a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` instead of your recoverer, which only prints the message. If you want the message as well, then your recoverer should call a DLPR afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

All your recoverer does is print that message

```java
(rec, ex) -> {
      System.out.println("publishing into DLT");
    }
```

You need to configure a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.